# Why is it recommended to include the private key used for assembly signing in open-source repositories?

Tags: c#, .net, open-source, signing, strongname

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad(v=vs.110).aspx), it is a recommended practice to include both the private and public keys used for strong-naming assemblies into the public source control system if you're developing open-source software:

> If you are an open-source developer and you want the identity benefits of a strong-named assembly, consider checking in the private key associated with an assembly into your source control system.

This is something that confuses me greatly. Making the private key public? Wouldn't the whole purpose and security of asymmetric cryptography be defeated in this case?

I see in the same article this note:

> Do not rely on strong names for security. They provide a unique identity only.

This does not help reduce my confusion. Why then use a private-public key pair if security is not the aim? Is the strong-naming mechanism in .NET using private-public key pairs in an inappropriate way? My guess is that I'm missing or misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 7):

Strong name signing is not for security, it is to guarantee uniqueness. It is so if two people make `Foo.dll v1.0.0.0` you have a way of telling them apart in the GAC.

If you have a open source library and you want your end user's `MyOpenSource.dll v1.0.0.0` to be able to be used as a replacement for the released `MyOpenSource.dll v1.0.0.0` then both the user's copy and the official copy must both be signed with the same key (or both must be not signed at all). That is why you would want to distribute it.

The strong name key is not for saying "This is a official, unmodified copy of `MyOpenSource.dll`", that is what [Authenticode signing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537359(v=vs.85).aspx) is for. It is only for preventing name collisions from different publishers.

Comment: So there's no harm in publishing that private key as long as it's used for and only for signing that particular assembly? Or, to put it another way, if Microsoft decided to open source all their .NET base class libraries on GitHub, would they include as well the .snk file used for signing those assemblies?

Comment: If they wanted to allow people to replace the official assemblies with their own copies in the GAC, yes. And as for harm, as long as the private key is only used for strong named signing it is fine to distribute it. If you are also using the same key to do authenticode signing then there is definite risk (But there is no reason not to use two separate keys)

Comment: It's a bit clearer now, but i'd still say that once you make that private key public you can't even guarantee uniqueness anymore. Anyone in the world can now create an assembly with exactly the same strong name. You lose all advantages you had when it stayed private. Even Jeffrey Richter in "CLR via C#" says that private keys used in assembly signing should be stored on secure devices and never shared across companies.

Comment: In reply to "The strong name key is not for saying "This is a official, unmodified copy of MyOpenSource.dll"". This is somewhat subjective. While the main reason to strong name sign an assembly is identification, you CAN enforce the signature if you want to. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree that signing your assemblies has no part in security. Yes, it is used to identify an assembly. And by default, the signature is NOT enforced. So in that regard, yes, the security is not directly affected only by signing. However you CAN use your key pair to enforce signature verification without having to dish out for a CA certificate. To do this however you must P/Invoke this function:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Friend Class NativeMethods
    <DllImport("mscoree.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
    Public Shared Function StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx(wszFilePath As String, fForceVerification As Byte, ByRef pfWasVerified As Byte) As Boolean
    End Function
End Class
```

From there, design a base class that your protected assemblies can inherit from:

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Public Class SignedClassBase
    Shared Sub New()
        VerifyAssemblySignature(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly())
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()
        VerifyAssemblySignature(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly())
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub VerifyAssemblySignature(assembly As Assembly)
        Dim wasVerified As Boolean
        If Not (NativeMethods.StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx(assembly.Location, True, wasVerified) AndAlso wasVerified) Then
            Throw New CryptographicException("Verification failed: Assembly signature did not match.")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

And then call the base constructor from your derived class:

```
Public Class Utils
    Inherits SignedClassBase

    Shared Sub New()
        RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(GetType(SignedClassBase).TypeHandle)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now if a modified assembly is instantiated, a CryptographicException will throw from the base class constructor, preventing the derived class from being used.

So while signing code alone is not directly tied to security, enforcing assembly signature can definitely add to whatever security you already have in place, in conjunction with strong obfuscation where needed. In this respect, the private key MUST remain secret. Sharing the private key in an open-source project is simply a way to make life easier for the developers involved. It would be MUCH better to instead sign the assemblies as part of the official build process, and keep your private key completely secret. Otherwise anyone can recompile an assembly with potentially malicious code and sign it with your private key, and distribute tainted copies of your project.

Comment: I'm glad we agree about the importance of keeping the private key private. As for the code sample, it took me a bit to mentally translate VB.NET to C# as i'm much more familiar with the latter, but i'm still not sure i understand where and when the Utils constructor must be called.

Comment: You don't have to call the derived class constructor, it is called by whatever invokes it. The first time you invoke a shared (or static in c#; my apologies I didn't see the c# tag originally) method in the Utils class, its shared constructor is invoked, which calls the base class constructor. And if you "var bleh = new Utils();", the public constructor is called, and again the base class constructor is run.